# Why Desmos is giving two different answers for integral of the form $\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\tan^{-1}(\cot(mx)\right)^2\:dx$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, periodic-functions, desmos

> Why Desmos is giving two different answers for integral of the form $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\tan^{-1}(\cot(mx)\right)^2\:dx,m \in \mathbb{N}$$

Firstly, I used the substitution $mx=\theta$. We get $dx=\frac{d\theta}{m}$, So
$$I=\frac{1}{m}\int_{0}^{m\pi}\left(\tan^{-1}(\cot \theta)\right)^2\:d\theta$$

Now since the Fundamental Period of $\cot \theta$ is $\pi$, the integral converts to

$$I=\frac{1}{m}\times m \times \int_0^{\pi}\left(\tan^{-1}(\cot \theta)\right)^2\:d\theta$$

Now when $0<\theta<\pi$, we have $$\tan^{-1}(\cot \theta)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$$
Thus, we get
$$I=\int_0^{\pi}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)^2\:d\theta=\frac{\pi^3}{12}=2.5838...$$

Now what I did is, I picked natural numbers $m=2022,2023$ and posted these on Desmos. Here is the Snapshot showing different results.

[image]

Any Comments?

Comment: It might not use sufficiently many sample points to resolve the rapid oscillations. Do you get more reasonable results for smaller $m$?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica's `NIntegrate` (for $m=2022$) spits out a couple of warning messages about slow convergence and returns 2.37641, so it's struggling too.

Comment: Could you please share a link to the calculation?

Comment: From my experience, Desmos is bad at integrating those types of functions that have really large integers like 2023 because it's not built to handle that much computational power.